# Are square-integrable representations of a general locally compact group tempered

Tags: rt.representation-theory, unitary-representations

Let $G$ be a locally compact unimodular group with center $Z$ and let $\omega$ be a unitary character of $Z$. To fix the discussion, an **irreducible** unitary representation $\pi$ with central character $\omega$ is

- **square integrable** if for all $u,v\in V_\pi$, the matrix coefficient $g\mapsto \left< gu,v\right>$ is square integrable when viewed as a function on $G/Z$, and
- **tempered** if $\pi$ is weakly contained in the right regular representation $\mathrm{L}^2(G)$. That is, for any compact $C\subseteq G$, $\varepsilon>0$ and unit vector $v\in V_\pi$, there is a unit vector $\psi\in \mathrm{L}^2(G)$ such that $|\left<gv,v\right>-\left<g\psi,\psi\right>|<\varepsilon$ for all $g\in C$.

(There are other equivalent definitions for temperedness when $G$ is a real or $p$-adic reductive  Lie group.)

It is not immediately obvious from the definitions that irreducible square-integrable representations are tempered, but it is known to be true in the following cases:

$Z=1$ (since then $\pi$ above can be embedded in $\mathrm{L}^2(G)$),

$G$ is a real or $p$-adic reductive Lie group.

$G=Z$, or $G$ is compact, or more generally $G$ is amenable (since any irreducible representation is tempered in the previous sense).

My question is whether this is true for general locally compact  groups. (Assume $G$ is unimdular and all irreducible unitary representations are admissible if this simplifies things.)

The question can be generalized even further as follows: Suppose that $Z$ is just a normal amenable subgroup of $G$ and let $\mathrm{L}^2_\omega(G/Z)$ denote the set of $(Z,\omega)$-equivariant functions $\psi:G\to \mathbb{C}$ such that 
$|\psi|$ is square integrable when viewed as a function on $G/Z$. Is it true that any irreducible representation of $G$ that is weakly contained in 
$\mathrm{L}^2_\omega(G/Z)$ ($G$ acts by right translations) is weakly contained in $\mathrm{L}^2(G)$?

Comment: Can I assume Type I as well? (I am thinking aloud here; this may be a red herring, since there exist amenable groups which are not Type I)

Comment: Yes. Assume also that the group is second countable.

Comment: A trivial comment:  not the matrix coefficient $g \mapsto \langle g u, v\rangle$, but only its absolute value, is defined on $G/Z$.

Comment: Dear Uriya, is being "tampered" related to properties of Caylet graphs (in a similar way that property-T is related to being an expander)? (I vaguely remember that I was told so but not any detail.)

Comment: @UriyaFirst So sorry for such a late comment, but could you please provide some references on the three known cases mentioned in the post? Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @HetongXu Case 1 is considered "standard" and I don't know if anyone has written it anywhere. The idea is that if $\pi$ is square integrable and $v\in V_\pi$ is nonzero, then $u\mapsto[g\mapsto\langle u,gv\rangle]:V_\pi\to L^2(G)$ is $G$-equivariant and nonzero. Case 2 is explained in Sec.2.4 of Hee Oh's paper DOI:10.1215/S0012-7094-02-11314-3. I think I took Case 3 from the Wikipedia entry on amenable groups, which quotes Pier's "Amenable locally compact groups". The compact case also follows readily from the Peter-Weyl Theorem.

Comment: @GilKalai I realized I never replied to your comment. I apologize. Loosely speaking, then answer is "yes". Being a Ramanujan Cayley graph (or complex) is related to temperdness of certain representations of the automorphism group of a $k$-regular tree. It is a little complicated to explain in a comment, I am afraid.

Comment: @UriyaFirst Thank you so much for your kind help!! :)